# Reflection C# to idenfify and sum

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to identify a property through reflection in c# then sum this value, but I think I'm using this in incorrect form.

```
var salarioTotal = 0.0;
foreach (var item in T.GetType().GetProperties())
{                     
  if (item.Name.ToString() == "Salario")
    salarioTotal += (Double)item.GetValue(T, null);

  String campo = (Convert.ToString(salarioTotal));

  item.SetValue(T, campo);
}
return T;
```

Comment: pls create a minimal example which we can use reproduce, i could guess what T is, but pls put some more effort in you question if you need precise answers

Comment: also, try to name your variables in english (at least in SO-questions), which makes it easier for us to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: if you need some info an how to ask a good question, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are your expected inputs and outputs? What exactly are you trying to do with salaryTotal?

Comment: Instead of Reflection, have you considered defining an interface?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `double` value for your property, creating a sum and then you are converting it to a `string` for setting the value. Uness your `Salario` property is of type `object`, this won't work. If your property is of type `double` (which I assum), you have to set the property value without converting it to a string first:

```
item.SetValue(T, salarioTotal);
```

One sidenote: Think about changing your property type from `double` to `decimal`, which is a much better choice for salary information, because it avoids rounding errors due to floating point operations.

Comment: His code is not creating a sum, it is basically just setting `salarioTotal` to `T.Salario` and god knows what he is trying to do with the call to `SetValue()` where he is trying to assign a `string` to what he previously suggested to be a `double`...

Comment: @nozzleman: I agree that the code has many issues. I pointed out an obvious error that will not work. You're right that he _probably_ means something else, but that is everyone's guess.

Comment: You're right, thats why I was asking for details ;)